# Bug with PlotLegends->Placed in GraphicsRow

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.1**

---

The FrontEnd of Mathematica 11.1.0 on my Windows 7 box runs permanently at 100% CPU when I execute the following command:

```
GraphicsRow[Table[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 13}, PlotLegends -> Placed[k, {Right, Bottom}]], {k, 1, 2}]]
```

The rendering works correctly, but the CPU keeps running.
The problem seems to be the combination of GraphicsRow[] (or its siblings like GraphicsColumn[], GraphicsGrid[]) with PlotLegends->Placed[]. When I minimize the notebook window or scroll the plot out of the area of view within the notebook, the CPU usage goes back to zero, reopening the window pushes the CPU again to 100%. Disabling Evaluation->"dynamic updating" removes the problem.

This condition is new in version 11. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I'm using Win 7 SP1 64 bits and an NVIDIA NVS 310 graphics card

Comment: Same on OS X 10.12.3 with M11.1.0.  I see constant 60-70% CPU usage by the front end.  Please report it to Wolfram.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior in 11.0.1 and 11.1 for Windows 10 (64-bit), albeit my Lenovo P50 just goes to around 18% CPU usage. The problem goes away if you only use *one* position specification, e.g. just `Right` or just `Bottom` instead of `{Right, Bottom}`.

Comment: When I evlauate the code and the graphics are displayed, my CPU usage jumps to ~15-20% on my Windows 10 machine. When i delete the output it drops back down  to <1% usage. When I plot `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]` it does not increase dramatically. in the same manner. FWIW I see the same jump in 11.1 and 11.0.1. This is NOT reproducible on v10.4.1. Please report to WRI.

Comment: The problem exists in 11.0.1 as well, but not in 10.4.1 (on OS X).

Comment: The problem will not come up when using `Placed[ k, {Bottom, Right} ]` on my machine...

Comment: I can reproduce it, so I'm reporting it.

Comment: Same problem on my laptop (also running Win 7 SP1 64 bit), so it seems to be somewhat hardware independent.

Comment: @gwr:  using Placed[ k, {Bottom, Right} ] puts the legend outside of the subplots, hence it's not the same as with {Right,Bottom}. The sequence must be {horizontal,vertical}.